# Entity Framework Core : invalid column name 'UserId1'

Tags: entity-framework-core, asp.net-identity, entity-relationship

I am trying to use Entity Framework Core / .NET 5 to interact with my databases.

When I try to query `DbContent.UserClaims` I get the following error:

> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Invalid column name 'UserId1'.

I am not sure where `UserId1` us coming from. I have a property called `UserId` which is the foreign key. Here are the relation mapping

Here is what I tried to do in the `DbContext` class

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(builder);

    builder.Entity<User>(user =>
    {
        user.HasKey(r => r.Id);
        user.HasMany(x => x.UserRoles).WithOne().HasForeignKey(x => x.UserId);
        user.HasMany(x => x.UserClaims).WithOne().HasForeignKey(x => x.UserId);
        user.HasMany(x => x.UserTokens).WithOne().HasForeignKey(x => x.UserId);
    });

    builder.Entity<UserClaim>(userClaim =>
    {
        userClaim.HasKey(r => r.Id);
        userClaim.HasOne(r => r.User).WithOne().HasForeignKey<UserClaim>(x => x.UserId);
    });
}
```

Here is the `UserClaim` class which is derived from [IdentityUserClaim](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetIdentity/blob/main/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework/IdentityUserClaim.cs)

```
public class UserClaim : IdentityUserClaim<string>
{
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the `User` class which is derived from [IdentityUser](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetIdentity/blob/main/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework/IdentityUser.cs)

```
public class User : IdentityUser<string>
{
    public virtual ICollection<UserToken> UserTokens { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<UserRole> UserRoles { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<UserClaim> UserClaims { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the query that EF5 is generating

```
SELECT [u].[Id], [u].[ClaimType], [u].[ClaimValue],[u].[UserId], [u].[UserId1]
FROM [UserClaims] AS [u]
```

How can I fix this issue in Entity Framework Core?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using shadow properties here, and on top of that, trying to add UserId foreign key to the User itself. Since UserId is an already defined property in that class, it's adding a suffix to the property name every time you're trying to add a foreign key in the user table by the same name.

It should be something like this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<UserClaim>()
        .Property<int>("UserForeignKey");

modelBuilder.Entity<UserClaim>()
    .HasOne(a => a.User)
    .WithMany(b => b.UserClaims)
    .HasForeignKey("UserForeignKey")
```

Read [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key) on how to configure Fluent API for shadow properties, and some other ways to use the Fluent API.

Comment: What in the world possessed the developer to think that was ok? Throw an error don't just assume there is a *1, *2 column.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out that this is called ***"shadow properties"***. It made searching for an explanation a lot easier!

Answer (score 1):

[Identity model customization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/customize-identity-model) has different samples, take care of this difference:

```cs
b.HasMany(e => e.UserRoles).WithOne()            // may cause invalid column name 'userid1'
b.HasMany(e => e.UserRoles).WithOne(e => e.User) // works
```